Как отсортировать выборку из двух разных таблиц БД
подскажите как отсортировать массив по дате и времени? [timestamp]
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [timestamp] => 2024-05-29 12:46:41
    [amount] => 1
    [text] => Администратор Antisocial_Insomnia заблокировал Test_Ban офф. на 31 дней. Причина: 1
)
Array
(
    [id] => 4
    [timestamp] => 2024-04-29 12:46:54
    [amount] => 1
    [text] => Администратор Antisocial_Insomnia заблокировал Test_Ban офф. на 31 дней. Причина: 1
)
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [timestamp] => 2024-04-29 12:46:53
    [amount] => 1
    [text] => Администратор Antisocial_Insomnia заблокировал Test_Ban офф. на 31 дней. Причина: 1
)
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [timestamp] => 2024-04-29 12:46:45
    [amount] => 1
    [text] => Администратор Antisocial_Insomnia заблокировал Test_Ban офф. на 31 дней. Причина: 1
)
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [timestamp] => 2024-04-30 12:30:42
    [amount] => 1
    [text] => [A] Alex_Line разбанил игрока Test_Ban
)

PHP код
<?php
require_once("includes/connection.php");
$sqltest = "SELECT * FROM logs_offban WHERE `text` LIKE '%Test_Ban%' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0,200; SELECT * FROM logs_unban WHERE `text` LIKE '%Test_Ban%' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0,200;";
$result=mysqli_multi_query($con,$sqltest);
do {
    if ($result = mysqli_store_result($con)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
echo '<pre>';
print_r($row);
echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
} while (mysqli_next_result($con));
?>


Дорогие новички! Пожалуйста, изучайте основы своей профессии! Чтобы потом не задавать вопросы, как почесать левой ногой правое ухо. Эти логи должны лежать в одной таблице. И выбираться сразу с нужной сортировкой, примитивным SQL запросом. Без вот этого всего ужаса.

Если уж у вас 2 таблицы, соберите запрос через union all и отсортируйте

Спасибо комментатору с ником SwaD
Признателен и благодарен за подсказанный UNION ALL, итоговый вариант сделал вот так.
$sqlt = "SELECT * FROM logs_offban WHERE `text` LIKE '%Test_Ban%' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM logs_unban WHERE `text` LIKE '%Test_Ban%' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0,200;";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sqlt);
$a = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
usort($a, function($c, $b) {
        return strtotime($c['timestamp']) < strtotime($b['timestamp']);
       });
foreach($a as $item):
if($item['timestamp'] != 0) {
 echo '<p>'.$item['timestamp'].' - '.$item['text'].'</p></pre>';
} endforeach;


И какое отношение этот ответ имеет к вопросу "как отсортировать массив"?

В этом же коде, он отсортирован так как мне нужно, а именно по дате. ( см. строки 3,4,5)

Этот код сортирует не массив, а результат SQL запроса. Ответ не имеет отношения к вопросу.

Измените название вопроса: как отсортировать выборку из двух разных таблиц или что то в этом духе, тогда и вопрос и ответ будут соответствовать друг другу
